# Проблема с ShareActionProvider

Tags: java, android

Пытаюсь сделать кнопку «поделиться» через `ShareActionProvider`. Но когда запускается `activity`, выдает ошибку. Пробовал на Android 4.1 и Android 6.0

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This is not supported, use MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider()
at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.getActionProvider(MenuItemImpl.java:648)
at ru.sergey.test.AboutActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(AboutActivity.java:26)
at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2476)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:362)
at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:92)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.onCreatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:331)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.preparePanel(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1357)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.doInvalidatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1637)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9$1.run(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:132)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Вот мой код

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AboutActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_about);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        MenuItem shareItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_share);
        mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(shareItem);

        return true;
    }

    public void doShare() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Текст");
        mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(intent);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();


        if (id == R.id.action_share) {
            doShare();
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: В ошибке сказано что вы совершили недопустимую операцию и вам надо было использовать `MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider()`. Больше ничем помочь не можем - получить доступ к файлам проекта по вашему IP у нас получилось, но там что-то с кодировкой и кода мы увидеть не можем

Comment: не помогло. Делал как тут https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/master/AppCompat/Share/app/src/main/java/com/commonsware/android/sap/MainActivity.java